# Copying a list of files with wildcards into a new folder

Tags: shell, file, command-line, cp

I don't have much experience with the command line, but essentially I have a list of files in a single folder as follows:

```
file1_a_1
file1_a_2
file2_b_1
file2_b_2
file3_c_1
file3_c_2
```

And I also have a text file with the files I want. However, this list does not have the full file path, instead, it looks like this:

```
file1_a file3_c
```

because I want to move all files that start with 30 or so specific codes (i.e. everything that starts with file1_a and file1_c for all the files that start with this).

I have tried:

```
cp file1_a* file3_c* 'dir/dest'
```

but this does not work. I have also tried the `find` command. I think I have to use a loop to do this but I cannot find any help on looping through files with a wildcard on the end.

Thanks in advance! I am working on a linux machine in bash.

Comment: If you are working on a linux machine with `bash`, then why didn't you use the `bash` or `linux` tags.  The `batch-file` tag is for Windows .bat files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the **xargs** command with **find** command and a pipe

find / -name xxxxx | xargs cp /..

Comment: could you expand on what you mean, I am not familiar with the args command or how to use a pipe. Thank you!!

Comment: find -name file[1,2,3]_[a,b,c]_[1,2] | xargs cp dir/dest

Comment: find command will output many names of files, xargs will take each file and copy it to the destination dir

Comment: a pipe here will redirect the output of command find to be the input of the command xargs and denoted by '|'